# overload shift operator << to allow chaining

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, chaining

I am struggling with the operator overloading since I want it to allow chaining

```
class A{
 int a;
public:
 void doSomething(char *str);
 A operator<<(char *str);
}
```

So I have this class and what I can do is take a string and do something, which is not important for this question.

What I now could do is

```
A *counter = new A();
counter->doSomething("hello");
```

If I implement the overloaded shift operator

```
A A::operator<<(char *str)
{
  this->doSomething(str);
  return this;
}
```

I am able to write it like this

```
A *counter = new A();
(*counter) << "hello";
```

I hope I didn't make a mistake here because now I'm wondering how i could allow chaining

```
(*counter) << "hello" << "test";
```

I know that with chaining it would do this

```
(*counter).operator<<("hello" << "test");
```

which clearly doesn't make any sense since there are two strings/char arrays
But I know there is a way to do this. I googled it but every question was only about chaining together instances of the same type

what I then tried was putting two arguments into the function and adding it as a friend ... I am not sure but maybe I have to make a new overloaded operator with the type `char*` or a stream object and make it as a friend of `A`?

Thanks for helping me, I guess there should be kind of an easy answer that I don't see right now.

Comment: Your operator would be better taking `const char*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return a reference to `*this`, so your return type needs to be `A&`:

```
A& operator<<(char *str)
{
  this->doSomething(str); // as before
  return *this;           // return reference to this instance.
}
```

Comment: Well, you *can* return by value and chain calls just fine. But you might want to explain why you usualy *want* to return by reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are two wrong assumptions in your question which I want to clear up.

1. When you want to call `operator<<` on pointers, you have to do this
   for every call, not only the first. This is why

   ```
   A *counter = new A();
   (*counter) << "hello";
   ```

   works, but

   ```
   (*counter) << "hello" << "test";
   ```

   doesn't. The second `operator<<` will be invoked on *the pointer*
   returned by the first, which is not what you want. You had to write
   (which is ugly):

   ```
   (*((*counter) << "hello")) << "test";
   ```
2. The shift operator can be chained and is then evaluated from left to
   right, this is why the following is another wrong assumption:

   > ```
   > A << "hello" << "test";
   > ```
   >
   > I know that with chaining it would do this
   >
   > ```
   > A.operator<<("hello" << "test");
   > ```

   It actually is evaluated like this:

   ```
   A.operator<<("hello").operator<<("test");
   ```

   which is, more verbose:

   ```
   ( A.operator<<("hello") ).operator<<("test");
   ```

Chaining operators is possible if the object returned by `operator<<` also
implements `operator<<`, so you could return a copy of `*this` which
is of type `A`. However, this would *copy* the object which is
unnecessary since it will be most probably only live very
temporarily and is only used once by the following operator.

So what you want to do is return a **reference** in `operator<<`, on which the next `operator<<` can be called. This avoids the copy:

```
A& operator<<(char *str)
{
    this->doSomething(str);
    return *this;
}
```

Returning a pointer is possible but will not result in what you want, as explained above. The syntax would be very ugly.

Comment: +1 - nice explanation.  Re "When you want to call `operator<<` on pointers, you have to do this for every call, not only the first." - that's true when `operator<<` is a member, but a non-member `T* operator<<(T*, const char*)` is also imaginable if bizarre....

Comment: Yes, it's possible but indeed bizarre. I'd not suggest overloading operators for any type of pointers on the left hand side. Simply because it looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

`operator <<` should returns reference for chaining.

```
A& operator<<(char *str);

A& A::operator<<(char *str)
{
  this->doSomething(str);
  return *this;
}
```

Should be used like

```
A counter;
counter << "hello" << "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A *counter = new A();
```

makes your 'counter' a pointer, not an object. To use the operator on A, you could use

```
(*counter) << "hello"
```

Furthermore, I would advise you to think again about overloading operators. While it often seems like a cool idea at first, it can easily lead to code that is hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: `(*A) << "hello"` should be `(*counter) << "hello"`.